# Disable focus hint of textInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I use attributes :

***xml attributes*** of textinputlayout or edittext :

`android:descendantFocusability ="beforeDescandants";
android:focusableInTouchMod="true"`

and ***AndroidManifest***: 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`

***java code*** :

`mEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
 mEditText.clearFocus();
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

But not work 
buil tools version 25 (i use pre 25 but Still don't work)

when load app

[image]

on focus in editText

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting :

```
android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"
```

for root/parent view and not for textInputLayout or editText itself.

That should work !

Comment: tanks , your code nice word but i want clicked out-side edittext again focus false